# In what condition we have $(K^{-1})^\ast = (K^\ast)^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, adjoint-operators

Suppose $X$ $Y$ are two finite dimensional Hilbert space. Assume $K$: $X\to Y$ is linear.

My question is, in what condition of $K$ that 
$$(K^{-1})^\ast = (K^\ast)^{-1}?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$K$ need to be invertible, this is the sufficing and necessary condition.